# Why there are some black block in my htop display?

Tags: linux, terminal, htop

The color of graph used to look fine, but I don't how it become so ugly recently, with a black block inside. My computer is Mac OS and I'm using default terminal to connect my remote server. Besides, I check it with `xshell` in my Windows laptop, it looks normal!

Furthermore, I set `export TERM=linux` in the `/etc/profile` in my remote server. I'm not sure whether this influences.

[image]

Anyone who know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!